# How separate release from subsequent branches in git?

Tags: git

I am a gitiot and have checked in a tagged git release. Problem is now branching off this when I integrate this I am not keeping nice separate release point. I want to not integrate back into this point so would prefer to branch off from a point ahead. How is this done in git?  thanks

Update: lots of feedback this question was not clear.  What happened is I branched off of a commit which I tagged as a release.  I want future branches to be off a commit beyond the tagged release.

Comment: What is that?  I think probably so.  What does the (no parents) part mean.  When I look at the project now in source safe each release is a node, and then a node just above it from which there are branches.  The branches do not occur on the release node.  But one above it.  So I want  it to continue as single line and be able to trace files all the way back but any new branches will be off node beyond the release.  I thought when I created a new branch this would happen automatically but that's not what what happened!

Comment: I'll be honest: I read your question thrice and I understand neither what you are asking nor what you are trying to do.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then you need to create new commit (use `--allow-empty`, if you do not want to make any changes) and start your branching from it.

Comment: You keep talking about "nodes". Do you mean _commits_? This question is in dire need of a screenshot or a diagram.

Comment: Yes, the node is the commit that I am taging as a release. So I don't want to branch off from here.  I want to keep one main through each sprint. End of sprint a release commit.  Then I want to create my development branches but not directly off the release

Comment: Yes, I am talking about commits.  I kind of think PetSerAI is what I am after. I do want to base everything off same main its just kind of from a point in time ahead of the release

Comment: Your question still isn't clear. PetSerAl's option might give the shape you want in your commit graph, but it's basically a no-op. I don't understand why you'd want to do that. Again, a screenshot or diagram would _dramatically_ improve this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to not integrate back into this point so would prefer to branch
>   off from a point ahead.

It sounds like you want to perform a [rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase).

Let's say on your `master` branch you have:

```
A <- B <- C <- D
```

Then you created a branch off of `A` called `mybranch`. You did some work, but now want `mybranch` to be based off of `C`.

To accomplish this, you could do:

```
git checkout mybranch
git rebase C
```

This will re-write the history of `mybranch` so if you had previously pushed `mybranch` you will need to force-push:

```
git push -f origin mybranch
```